# Is there a cap limit to the Ads number we can query Admob Flutter?

Tags: flutter, admob, native-ads, google-mobile-ads

I would simply like to know if there is a limit to the number of `NativeAd`s `Object` we can `load()` from `AdMob` using `Flutter` ?

I would like for example making a `for` loop of 10 ads.
When the list containing these ads has a `length=1` (after calling `dispose()` and remove seen / old ones), I query 9 more ads etc...

Does it sound realistic ?

It's working fine with `test ads`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you should create 10 Ads units, do not use same ad unit, technically there is no limit if you create them using different ads units but don't go over board.

I know from experience that I can use 130 different ads units without a problems.

Some SDKs are using this technique to try to figure out AdMob eCPM before mediation, because of that I think AdMob is trying to combat this behavior, so this is why I told you "don't go overboard"

Comment: Thanks again for your answer :). Yes my only goal is to have enough ads to display in my UI (lists), not loading hundreds anyway but batches of 5-10 maximum.